# If I have a table showing different values, and a formula to display min/max, is there a way to display the corresponding cell?

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say that I have the following table:

Bananas    4
Apples     9
Oranges    6
Peanuts    24

Is there a way to make a formula that will display the corresponding A cell for the min/max value in column B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such Qs may be better suited to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) however, assuming your text is in ColumnA and your numbers in ColumnB, for the maximum please try:

```
=Index(A:A,match(max(B:B),B:B,0))
```

For the minimum as above but replace `ax` with `in`.

In both cases only the first value will be matched, where there is more than one instance of the same max/min value.